# Java get date of week in short form

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Hi I have a java application where I want to work out if a date string has got the day of the week.

```
//create the date variable
DateFormat dppomonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd ''yy");

//find if the string contains "Fri"
private void dppomonthActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(!dppomonth.getDate().toString().contains("Fri")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Select Friday Only...");
        dppomonth.setDate(null);
    }
}
```

the `getDate()` function has been deprecated how do I find if the string contains `"Fri"`

```
if(!dppomonth.getDate().toString().contains("Fri"))
```

Comment: which java version are you using ? java 6, java 7, java 8

Comment: If you are using Java 8, and you want to check if the day is `FRIDAY` or not you can use `if (LocalDate.now().dayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {}`
Where you can replace `LocalDate.now()` with any `LocalDate`

Comment: I am using java 8 when I use your example I get cannot find symbol  if (!dppomonth.dayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {

Comment: @DannyYounes, the method is called `getDayOfWeek​()`. Try.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn’t compile, and I haven’t understood exactly what you are trying to do with it. I get “The method getDate() is undefined for the type DateFormat”. Could you specify a couple of example date strings and the expected result for each?

Comment: I am looking at [the documentation for the DateFormat class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and I see no getDate or setDate methods.  Are you sure the code in your question is the code in your program?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `getDate()` method is deprecated.

you can use the `Calendar` class like this:

```
    DateFormat dppomonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd ''yy");
   if (dppomonth.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY){
}
```

Comment: On the variable "dppomonth" I am getting cannot find symbol not sure why

Comment: it depends on how to code is written but its look like a compile error.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Calendar` to make such check like

```
Date date = ...;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

if (dayOfWeek != Calendar.FRIDAY) {
    System.out.println("Please Select Friday Only...");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re after something like this (the question is not completely clear):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d ''uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateString = "Apr 5 '18";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
    if (! date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Select Friday Only...");
    }
```

As the code stands it does show the message since Apr 5 2018 is a Thursday.

Since you are using Java 8 (and even if you didn’t), I recommend you avoid `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Instead I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.